# Trouble binding C-return: C- must prefix a single character

Tags: key-bindings, keymap

This is what I have:

```
(add-hook 'magit-status-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (local-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") 'magit-diff-visit-file-other-window)))
```

Opening a magit-status buffer fails with "C- must prefix a single character, not return".

There are several related questions, but their solutions (for example moving the `<>` around `return` instead of the whole string) don't work. Using `RET` instead of `return` doesn't work either.

Emacs 26.1

Comment: `(local-set-key (kbd "C-<return>") #'magit-diff-visit-file-other-window)` works fine for me. What happens when you try that?

Comment: Typo on the placement of <

Comment: @Dan: Both of these return the same thing (`[C-return]`): `(kbd "C-<return>")` and `(kbd "<C-return>")`.

Comment: OP: Are you using Emacs in terminal mode instead of with a graphic display? Does your terminal support pseudo-function keys such as `<return>`? What does `C-h k` tell you when you hit the Return key?

Comment: I get that error from `(kbd "C-return")` (i.e., no `<` at all), is it possible you have that expression somewhere else in your config?

Comment: What does `C-h v magit-status-mode-hook` show you?  Config experiments of the form `(add-hook HOOK (lambda ...))` are a great way to end up with multiple incorrect lambda expressions in your HOOK variable.  This is one of the reasons why you shouldn't use `lambda` with hooks.  Write a named function, and add the function symbol to the hook.  That way you don't need to *remove* each incorrect lambda before adding a replacement.

Comment: @phils: you got it, thanks. I thought about restarting a fresh emacs session between changes for a while, then I forgot. Something good came out of it: I'll avoid lambdas in hooks from now on (until I forget). You could make your comment an answer.

Comment: ...which is why [use package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/README.md) is preferable to hooks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the comments we established that the problem wasn't the code shown in the question:

```
(add-hook 'magit-status-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (local-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") 'magit-diff-visit-file-other-window)))
```

The problem was the use of this pattern:

```
(add-hook 'HOOK (lambda ...))
```

When that pattern is used, updating the code of that `(lambda...)` function necessitates explicitly *removing the original/bad lambda from the hook variable* before adding a new updated version -- otherwise *both* functions will be called when the hook runs.

So the problem was that an earlier attempt (with a bad key binding syntax) was still being executed.

Inspecting <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `magit-status-mode-hook` showed that the old lambda was still present.

---

The better pattern is:

```
(add-hook 'magit-status-mode-hook 'my-magit-status-mode-hook)

(defun my-magit-status-mode-hook ()
  "Custom `magit-status-mode' behaviours."
  (local-set-key (kbd "<C-return>") 'magit-diff-visit-file-other-window))
```

As the named function can subsequently be updated without also needing to touch the hook variable.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well when I was trying to use `C-<return>` for another command in elpy. I managed to resolve it by first looking up the global key binding for `C-<return>` (try `C-h k` then type `C-<return>` to see what Emacs thinks is assigned to that key). In my situation, `C-<return>` was bound to CUA mode.

Then go into your configuration file and first set that binding to `nil`. In my situation, it looked like this:

```
;; Add keybindings for python that override CUA mode rect
(define-key cua-global-keymap [C-return] nil)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-RET") 'elpy-shell-send-statement-and-step)
```