# Ctrl-Alt-Enter: Add a new top-level heading and the current date

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

I'm trying to configure Ctrl-Alt-Enter to insert a new top-level heading and the current date in the following format:

```
* [2023-02-07 Tue]
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
(defun heading-date ()
    (interactive)
    (org-insert-heading)
    (insert (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a]"))
)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-return") 'heading-date)
```

However, when I press Ctrl-Alt-Enter I get this error in Emacs:

```
<C-M-return> is undefined
```

I've also tried reversing the order of `C` and `M` for experimentation's sake but of course that did not help:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-C-return") 'heading-date)
```

**How can I capture the Ctrl-Alt-Enter combination to run this function?**

Answer (score 1):

Ten minutes after posting I come up with the solution! **))**

It turns out to bind `return` the entire binding must be surrounded with brackets `<>`. So this is the binding:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-M-return>") 'heading-date)
```

Answer found from [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52638/trouble-binding-c-return-c-must-prefix-a-single-character) after noticing the error on startup `error C-M- must prefix a single character, not return`. Lesson learned: **Watch those startup errors!**

Comment: When you are unsure about the notion of a key, just `C-h k` and press the key[s].

Comment: @nichijou Thank you. That is useful information, but I do not believe that it would have helped identify _how_ to bind that key combination.

Comment: Presumably this is only useful in an Org mode buffer. If that's the case, then you'd be better off binding the key in `org-mode-map`, rather than the global map: `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-M-<return>") #'heading-date)`. Note also that you can evaluate the `kbd` function with any argument in your `*scratch*` buffer to see what it returns: switch to that buffer, type the first form you tried, `(kbd "M-C-return")`, press `C-j` after the closing paren to evaluate it and in this case, you'll get an error, so you know the string is wrong.

Comment: Terrific, thank you NickD!